APT assumptions
Suppose an investor identifies an asset with return $R_i$ whose excess return, when regressed on the market portfolio with return $R_M$ and a (zero-cost) long-short portfolio with return $R_{LS}$ gives:
$$ R_i - R_f = \alpha_i + \beta_i (R_M - R_f) + \nu_i R_{LS} + \epsilon_i $$
The long-short portfolio is market neutral that is $R_{LS}$ is uncorrelated with the market. Further $E[R_{LS}] = 0$ and $\text{Var}[R_{LS}] = \sigma^2_{LS}$, $E[R_M] = \mu_M$, $\text{Var}[R_M] = \sigma^2_M$, and $\text{Var}[\epsilon_i] = \sigma^2_\epsilon$.
What conditions on $\alpha_i$, $\beta_i$, $\nu_i$ are required for the model to be consistent with the APT (arbitrage pricing theory)?
The answer I was given is $\alpha_i = 0$ for most $i$, $\beta_i$ and $\nu_i$ unrestricted. However, I really don't see why. For me APT says just that if we have returns are modeled with factors then the expectation of the return satisfies some form.
